# How do i get a button to display one image instead of all the images in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the react-image-lighbox npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-lightbox and i am trying to get it to work with my custom code. I have a gallery and i am trying to get it to display an image in a lightbox when you click on a button in the array. At the moment when you click on any of the buttons it opens up all of them at the same time in an array. I need to have it filtered so that it only opens the image that you clicked on not all of them.

At the moment i am playing around with filter and if statements to try and find a solution.

Example of some of the state passed down through props.

```
portfolioContent: [
            {
                id: uuidv1(),
                imgURL: image01,
                text: 'Copy 1',
                section: 1,
                work:
                    'https://images2.minutemediacdn.com/image/upload/c_crop,h_1193,w_2121,x_0,y_64/f_auto,q_auto,w_1100/v1565279671/shape/mentalfloss/578211-gettyimages-542930526.jpg'
            },
            {
                id: uuidv1(),
                imgURL: image02,
                text: 'Copy 2',
                section: 1,
                work:
                    'https://images2.minutemediacdn.com/image/upload/c_crop,h_1193,w_2121,x_0,y_175/f_auto,q_auto,w_1100/v1554921998/shape/mentalfloss/549585-istock-909106260.jpg'
            }
]

<Main portfolio={this.state.portfolioContent} />
<PortfolioWork work={this.props.portfolio} section="1" />
```

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Lightbox from 'react-image-lightbox';
import 'react-image-lightbox/style.css'; // This only needs to be imported once in your app

const images = [
  '//placekitten.com/1500/500',
  '//placekitten.com/4000/3000',
  '//placekitten.com/800/1200',
  '//placekitten.com/1500/1500',
];

export default class LightboxExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      photoIndex: 0,
      isOpen: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { photoIndex, isOpen } = this.state;

    return (
        <Fragment>
        {this.props.work.map(portfolio => {
            if (portfolio.section === Number(this.props.section)) {
                return (
                    <div className="portfolio-content" key={portfolio.id}>
                        <img src={portfolio.imgURL} alt={portfolio.text} />
                        <p>{portfolio.text}</p>
                        <a href={portfolio.work}>See work</a>
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: true })}>
          Open Lightbox
        </button>

        {isOpen && (
          <Lightbox
            mainSrc={portfolio.imgURL}
            nextSrc={images[(photoIndex + 1) % images.length]}
            prevSrc={images[(photoIndex + images.length - 1) % images.length]}
            onCloseRequest={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}
            onMovePrevRequest={() =>
              this.setState({
                photoIndex: (photoIndex + images.length - 1) % images.length,
              })
            }
            onMoveNextRequest={() =>
              this.setState({
                photoIndex: (photoIndex + 1) % images.length,
              })
            }
          />
        )}

                    </div>
                );
            }
        })}
    </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Clicking on a button opens up that image in a lightbox. At the moment if you click on any button it opens up all of the images at the same time in a lighbox.

Comment: You have to manage array of isOpen flags and set true for index in array and to all other false and  rebuild the state

Comment: Thanks for your help i found another solution that worked i'm sure yours would have worked too. It was just harder to implement at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. So i created a function in the main App.js file which took in an object. And then i passed down that function to the component through props and attached it to a click event. So that when the user clicks on the button it is assigned to its corresponding object. I then set that object to state and made the selected image object the main source for the lightbox image which gets displayed.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Lightbox from 'react-image-lightbox';
import 'react-image-lightbox/style.css'; // This only needs to be imported once in your app
​
export default class LightboxExample extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
​
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };
    }
​
    render() {
        const { isOpen } = this.state;
​
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {this.props.work.map(portfolio => {
                    if (portfolio.section === Number(this.props.section)) {
                        return (
                            <div key={portfolio.id}>
                                <div className="portfolio-content">
                                    <img src={portfolio.imgURL} alt={portfolio.text} />
                                    <p>{portfolio.text}</p>
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            this.setState({ isOpen: true });
                                            this.props.onImageSelect(portfolio);
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        See work
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    {isOpen && (
                                        <Lightbox
                                            mainSrc={this.props.selectedImage.imgURL}
                                            onCloseRequest={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    }
                })}
            </Fragment>
        );
```